# Determinant of a tridiagonal matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recurrence-relations, determinant, tridiagonal-matrices

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$, and let $A$ be a $(2N+1) \times (2N+1)$ tridiagonal matrix of the following form
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots \\
\vdots &(\nu-2)^2 & 1& 0&0&0&\vdots\\
\vdots & 1 &(\nu-1)^2 &1&0&0&\vdots\\
\vdots & 0&1&\nu^2&1&0&\vdots\\
\vdots & 0&0&1&(\nu+1)^2&1&\vdots\\
\vdots & 0&0&0&1&(\nu+2)^2&1\\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & 1 &\dots  &
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The matrix is "centered" in the sense that $A_{ii}=A_{2N+2-i}=(N+1-i)^2$

I would like to calculate its eigenvalues, I tried to expand the determinant of $A-\lambda \; \mathrm{Id}$ with respect to the first and last column to have a recurrence relation, but it does not seem to bring an easy recurrence relation I could solve...

Comment: What is your recurrence relation?  You could try row operations to make it triangular.

Comment: So the central element is zero and the diagonal is $\{\ldots, 9,4,1,0,1,4,9,\ldots\}$, right?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes this is correct !

Comment: @MichaelBurr I haven't managed yet to get this relation, I will try to make it triangular ! thanks :)